# What's the free indexed category/ free indexed monad in the bicategory of endospans?

Tags: category-theory, higher-category-theory

In Coq a loose approximation to the free monad over a polynomial endofunctor might be.

```
Polymorphic Cumulative Record Poly := {
   pos: Type ;
   dir: pos -> Type ;
}.
Inductive free (p: Poly) A :=
| pure (v: A)
| roll x (p: dir p x -> free p A).
```

A monad in the bicategory of spans in Set is a category. Loosely the free category of an endospan is something like:

```
Polymorphic Cumulative Record span A B := {
   s: Type ;
   p1: s -> A ;
   p2: s -> B ;
}.
Arguments p1 {A B}.
Arguments p2 {A B}.
Inductive free {Obj} (p: span Obj Obj): Obj -> Obj -> Type :=
| id A: free p A A
| compose {A B C}: free p B C -> free p A B -> free p A C
| op x: free p (p1 p x) (p2 p x)
.
```

I'm having trouble untangling what the free indexed category of an endospan should be.

An endospan in a slice category $\text{Set}/\Gamma$ indexed over a set kind of makes sense. But maybe there is a more natural definition?

I'm not quite sure how to interpret the equivalent of a slice category for spans. I know comma categories are sort of like pullbacks. A straightforward reinterpretation of a slice as for some object $x$ a map between a constant span and the identity span on $x$ seems very quirky though.

$$ \text{Obj}/\Gamma = \Sigma \, (x: \text{Obj}) , \; \text{id}_x \Rightarrow \,  ! \Gamma $$

A more involved idea is to make $\text{Obj}$ a category and then look at the free monad of an indexed two sided discrete fibration $\text{Obj}/\Gamma \rightarrow \text{Obj}/\Gamma^{\text{op}}$. You get this weird profunctor equivalent of a free monad but I find this really confusing.

Comment: I don't exactly get what you're after: a category is a monad in Span; an endospan is just a graph (I love to see this using profunctors: if $A$ is a set, and $p : A \rightsquigarrow A$ is a profunctor, then there is a graph having $A$ as vertices, and as many edges $a\to a'$ as there are elements $x \in p(a,a')$). Now, applying the free construction on a graph amounts to applying it to the profunctor.

Comment: @fosco So I'm interested in carrying a typing environment around like a set of free variables and I'm not quite sure how something like a category indexed by a discrete category of a list of variables would translate to the vocabulary of graphs/spans. A span in Set/Env seems wonky to me or at least incomplete. I want to understand what an indexed span means. Maybe it could be useful for a subtyping for example.

Comment: Ahah I think a free monad over a displayed category [C, Span(Set)] is what I want. https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/displayed+category